# How to break a loop by setting a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I wrote an ajax call with two `for loop`.
 The first cycle looks for a key whose value is `"city"`, the second one search for a key whose value is `"hamlet"`.
A table is displayed if any of these two values is found.

I want to set a new variable `var valueFound` to indicate that the values in the first cycle have already been found, in order to say "if the value in the first cycle has been found, don't search for the second value in the other for loop".

What I want is avoiding duplicates in the search results in case both of the values are found.

The code I wrote so far is the following:

```
success: function (data) {                 
  for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
    let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
    if (typeCity === "city") {
      let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
      for (let i = 0; i < francigena.tappe.length; i++) {
        let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
        let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
        let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;
        if (city === nameCity) {                                    
          $('#tabellaEconteuti').show(); 
        } 
      };
    }  
    else if (typeCity === "hamlet") {
      let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
      for (let i = 0; i < francigena.tappe.length; i++) {
        let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
        let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
        let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;
        if (city === nameCity) {
          $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();
        }
      };
    };
  }                   
 },
```

When in the JSON array `typeCity === "city"` or `typeCity === "hamlet"` no problem, BUT it both of the values are found I get duplicates in the search results.

How can I set such a variable `var valueFound` to indicate that some values have already been found and breaking the loop?

Comment: set a variable outside for loop and update it's value to true if you find any one of the value, or you can use `find` method

Comment: @CodeManiac how may I update its value? Do you mean a boolean variable?

Comment: Yes boolean value, by default keep it false and change it to true as soon as any of the value is found

Comment: As far as I can tell, all that code does is call `$('#tabellaEconteuti').show();`, potentially multiple times. How does that work? How does calling show() on a single element multiple times "get duplicates in the search results"?

Comment: In addition to what @ChrisG said, both branches appear to be doing exactly the same thing; why don't you just use `if (typeCity === "city" || typeCity === "hamlet")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function (data) {                 
  cont featuresMapByCityType = dataFeaturesMapByCityType(data.features); 
  cont tappesMapByCityType = getTappeMapByCity(francigena.tappe); 
    let feature = featuresMapByCityType['city'] || featuresMapByCityType['hamlet'];
    if (feature) {
      let nameCity = feature.properties.geocoding.name;
      cont tappe = getTappeMapByCity[nameCity];
        if (tappe && tappe.city === nameCity) {                                    
          $('#tabellaEconteuti').show(); 
        } 
    }               
 };
function dataFeaturesMapByCityType(features) {
     let featuresMapByCityType = {};
     features = features || [];
     features.forEach(feature => {
         featuresMapByCityType{feature.properties.geocoding.type} = feature;
     });
    return featuresMapByCityType;
 }
function getTappeMapByCity(tappes) {
     let tappesMapByCityType = {};
     tappes = tappes || [];
     tappes.forEach(tappe => {
         tappesMapByCityType{tappe[i].city} = tappe;
     });
    return tappesMapByCityType;
 }
```

I have organized the code and removed multiple for loops, not sure the francigena comes from. this is a rough organization of code. This might help you.